Is interrupting someone's sexual intercourse considered a sin in Hinduism?
Is interrupting someone's sexual intercourse considered a sin in Hinduism? Is it a punishable offence? What kind of punishment is prescribed? Is it categorically mentioned anywhere?

Yes. See Adi Parva (MBh.) - where Pandu was cursed by rishi Kindama.

I know that incident. However, is it forbidden categorically? I mean Pandu was cursed by the Rishi. But even if someone does not curse, would it be a punishable sin?

Yes. While cursing, Kindama says one must not disturb during maithuna. I can dig the actual statements later.

Another example I could think of is Kalmashapada (when he was possessed by Rakshasa) eating brahmanas who were consummating. He was cursed not to ever have contact with wife and Vasishtha becomes father to his children. (Again, I need to dig to find the exact words.)

@Kanthri Kindama's example isn't good, because he never said against interruption of maithuna, his only reason was that it was pāpa on the part of Pāṇḍu to slay him as a deer when he was engaged in intercourse. It would have been fine, if Pāṇḍu killed the deer, when it wasn't doing intercourse, in line with his Kṣatriyadharma.
So, it's not about disturbing in intercourse exactly, but killing an animal or a person, who is having intercourse

interruption by killing and ordinary interruption aren't same

@Bingming I am talking about the ordinary interruption.

I am aware about that @AmritenduMukhopadhyay

Siva Purana, Rudra Samhita, Kumara Khanda, Chapter 1

If a person devises methods for separating a man and a woman at the time of intercourse, from one birth to another birth, he will be separated from his wife and sons. He is dislodged from his jnana. His deeds and prosperity in this world are destroyed. When the sinner dies, he goes to Kalasutra (the name of a hell) for one hundred thousand years.


When Shakra was engaged in intercourse with Rambha, Durvasa, the great Indra among sages, separated them. Consequently, he was separated from his wife.


When Kama was engaged in intercourse with Ghritachi, Guru restrained him. Within six months, Chandra abducted his wife.


Yes. even looking at sexual intercourse causes sinful effects except if it is done by infants or those who are no longer passionate about it.

From Brahmanda Purana Section 3, Chapter 41 as told by Vinayaka:

He who spoils the pleasure of a man and a women seated together in the same seat, shall surely go to hell.

Especially this is definitely decided that a Brāhmaṇa shall never see his father, preceptor or king, enjoying privacy.

Whether out of carnal desire or otherwise, if a person sees another person inclined to sexual intercourse, he shall have to suffer
certainly separation from his wife in the course of seven births.

He is a base man—he who looks at the buttocks, breasts and face of another man’s wife, his mother, sister or daughter”.


Bhargava replied:-

O, unusual and unprecedented words have been heard from your mouth. Have they come out due to your mistake or have you uttered them
jocularly?

The restriction from the scripture cited by you refers to lovers and passionate ones prone to aberrations. There is no fault in case of
an infant or a person devoid of passionate feelings.



